# Boundary condition ODE

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solving the non-linear ODE $\gamma^{\prime \prime} = \gamma \gamma'$ gives the solution
\begin{align*}
    \gamma(t) = C_1 \tan{\bigg(\frac{C_1 t + C_1C_2}{2}\bigg)}
\end{align*}
my two boundary conditions are
\begin{align*}
    \gamma(0) &=  x\\
    \gamma(1) &= y
\end{align*}
I am trying to find $C_1(x,y)$ and $C_2(x,y)$ explicitly. After trying to play around with trig identities, and re-writing tan as a product of exponentials I just cant figure out if it's possible.

I tried simplifying by setting $x=0$, and the furthest I get is that $C_2=0$ and $C_1 \tan(C_1/2) = y$. However, even in this simplified case there doesn't seem like there is a way to represent $C_1$ explicitly in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''(t)=y'(t)y(t)$$
It's obvious that WA 's answer is coorect
$$2y''=2y'y$$
First integration gives us:
$$2y'=y^2+C_1$$
This DE is separable:
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{y^2+C_1}=\dfrac 12 t+C_2$$
For $C_1>0$ use $arctan$ function to integrate LHS.
$$ \arctan \left (\dfrac {y}{\sqrt {C_1}} \right )=\sqrt {C_1}(\dfrac 12t+C_2)$$
$$\implies y(t)=\sqrt {C_1} \tan (\sqrt {C_1}(\dfrac 12t+C_2))$$
More simply $(C_1>0)$:
$$\implies y(t)={2C_1} \tan \left (  {tC_1}+C_2 \right)$$
For $C_1=0$ it's easy to integrate the DE. Otherwise $(C_1<0)$ use partial fraction decomposition and $ln$ functions to integrate LHS.

What is not clear is the boundary condtions that depends on variable $x,y$. The $C$ are constants not functions of $x,y$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are constants. What do you think about my "risky" solution ?

Comment: Oh sorry Claude I didn't know op meant by that constant values. Nice answer Clayde as usual. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: For the fun, look at my edit !!! Cheers :-)

Comment: Great I saw your calculations ite's rzlly precise. You are really good at numerical approximations Clausee @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: I have doing that for 60+ years and it is my passion. I don't consider that I am a mathematian. A numerician, yes I am.

Comment: Oh my God you have lots of experience I have read long time ago that on your profile Claude. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: I found the infinite series. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$Y''(x)=Y(t)Y'(t) \implies Y''=\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt}(Y^2) \implies \int Y'' dt=\frac{1}{2} Y^2  \implies  Y'= \frac{Y^2}{2}+A^2/2$$
$$\implies \int \frac{2dY}{Y^2+A^2}=\int \frac{dt}{2}+C \implies \frac{1}{A} \tan^{-1}(Y/A)=t/2+c \implies Y=A \tan(At/2+B)$$ Given that $Y(0)=x \implies A \tan B=x$.
Given $Y(1)=y \implies A \tan(A/2+B)=y$
Finally, we get $$y=A \left( \frac{A \tan(A/2)+x}{A-x\tan(A/2)} \right).$$

Comment: Ah, that is what I get for being lazy. Can you explain why WolframAlpha gave me that solution? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Y%27%27+%3D+Y+Y%27

Comment: In the first integration the integration constant is missing or set to zero. So this answer only gives a one-parameter family of solutions, while the full solution has two parameters/integration constants..

Comment: This seems to be wrong

Comment: Yes, Sorry, Now I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to solve
$$c_1 \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} c_1 c_2\right)=x \tag 1$$
$$c_1 \tan \left(\frac{1}{2} c_1 (c_2+1)\right)=y \tag 2$$
Expanding $(2)$ and using $(1)$ in the result leads to
$$\frac{c_1 \left(c_1 \tan \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)+x\right)}{c_1-x \tan
   \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)}=y \tag 3$$ and then
$$c_2=\frac{2 }{c_1}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{c_1}\right)\tag 4$$ but $(3)$ seems to be impossible to solve analytically.

Trying, let $$z=\tan \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)$$ and solving $(3)$ would give
$$c_1=\frac{y-x\pm\sqrt{(x-y)^2-4 x y z^2}}{2 z}$$ which is still a nightmare. Just forget it and think about numerical methods since you have only $(3)$ to solve.

If you are **very** optimistic, using Taylor around $c_1=0$ would give
$$y=-\frac{2 x}{x-2}+\frac{ \left(x^2-6 x+12\right)}{6
   (x-2)^2}c_1^2+\frac{ \left(x^3-12 x^2+60 x-120\right)}{360
   (x-2)^3}c_1^4+O\left(c_1^6\right)$$ and using series reversion
$$c_1=   \sqrt{\frac{6(x-2)^2}{x^2-6 x+12}}t-\frac{
   \left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} (x-2) \sqrt{\frac{(x-2)^2}{x^2-6 x+12}}
   \left(x^3-12 x^2+60 x-120\right)\right)}{10 \left(x^2-6
   x+12\right)^2}t^3+\cdots$$ where $t=\sqrt{\frac{2 x}{x-2}+y}$.

Checking for $x=1$ and $y=3$, the exact result is $c_1=0.864655$, $c_2=1.98427$ while the approximation gives
$$c_1=\frac{909 }{490}\sqrt{\frac{3}{14}}\approx 0.858745$$
$$c_2=\frac{980}{909} \sqrt{\frac{14}{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{490
   }{909}\sqrt{\frac{14}{3}}\right)\approx 2.00583$$

**Edit**

For the fun of it, I made the series expansion to $O\left(c_1^{14}\right)$; this leads to
$$c_1=\frac{965768149315295493 }{517042695769600000}\sqrt{\frac{3}{14}}\approx 0.864655$$ which, in turn, gives $c_2\approx 1.98427$ that is to say *exactly* the solution.

**Update**

Instead of a series expansion, I built the $[2,6]$ Padé approxiamnt of
$$\frac{c_1 \left(c_1 \tan \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)+x\right)}{c_1-x \tan
   \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)}-y$$ (this is equivalent to an $O\left(c_1^{10}\right)$ expansion) and the result write
$$c_1^2=\frac{42 (x (y+2)-2 y) \left(x^3 (y+12)-12 x^2 (y+10)+60 x (y+8)-120 (y+6)\right)  } {\text{denominator} }$$ the denominator being
$$x^4 (y (y+18)+102)-6 x^3 (3 y (y+16)+238)+72 x^2 (2 y (y+14)+119)-84 x (7 y
   (y+12)+300)+1008 (y (y+10)+30)$$ For the working example, it gives
$$c_1=\sqrt{\frac{714}{955}}\approx 0.864664\quad \text{and} \quad c_2=\sqrt{\frac{1910}{357}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{955}{714}}\right)\approx 1.98424$$

Answer (score 0):

*I prefer to add another answer,just dedicated to the solution of equation $(3)$ of my previous answer and few othe aspects.*

We had
$$\frac{c_1 \left(c_1 \tan \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)+x\right)}{c_1-x \tan
   \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)}=y \tag 3$$ which can rewrite
$$f(c_1)=a\,c_1 \cos \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right)
   +\sin \left(\frac{c_1}{2}\right) \left(c_1^2+b\right)=0$$ where $a=x-y$ and $b=xy$.

which, from a numerical point of view, is much better conditioned than $(3)$ since no more discontinuities.

Going to expansions around $c_1=0$, we can then write
$$\frac{f(c_1)}c=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{ (2 a+b)+4( a-2) n-16 n^2}{2^{2 n+1}\,(2 n+1)!}\,c_1^{2n}$$ which, if truncated to $O\left(c_1^{2p+2}\right)$, reduce the problem to a polynomial of degree $p$ in $c_1^2$.

For the worked example $(x=1,y=3)$ corresponding to $(a=-2,b=3)$, the smallest positive solutions are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & c_1 \\
 1 &  0.8528028654 \\
 2 &  0.8647660893 \\
 3 &  0.8646548281 \\
 4 &  0.8646553082\\
 5 &  0.8646553069 \\
 6 &  0.8646553069
\end{array}
\right)$$

Let
$$A_k=(-1)^n \frac{ (2 a+b)+4( a-2) n-16 n^2}{2^{2 n+1}\,(2 n+1)!}$$ and the  $[2,6]$ Padé approximant gives
$$c_1^2=\frac{A_0 \left(A_1^3-2 A_0 A_1 A_2+A_0^2 A_3\right)}{A_1^4-3 A_0 
   A_1^2A_2+2 A_0^2 A_3 A_1+ A_0^2A_2^2-A_0^3 A_4}$$